# "Data checksum condition" in Visual Studio's "SQL Server Unit Test" always return different checksum on same data

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, unit-testing

I want to do SQL Unit Test that will help me rewrite big t-sql query with many subqueries, and will automatically check that data before and after rewriting are same. In most parts of query "Data Checksum Condition" Assert do this work as i need.

But i have little simple subquery, and Unit test always fails on him - for unknown reason "Data Checksum Condition" returns different checksum each run. And so Unit Test fails...

Subquery just has join two tables on binary[16] key, and returns int-value from second table:

```
select
        [ProductStatusID] = [enum].[ID]
from
        [dbo].[info]
    join
            [dbo].[enum]
        on
                [info].[ref] = [enum].[ref]
```

(this is all unit test code)

[info] table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[info](
  [ref] [binary](16) NOT NULL,
)
GO
```

[enum] table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[enum](
   [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [ref] [binary](16) NOT NULL
)
```

[enum] has 23 rows, [info] has 223086 rows

This two tables absolutely static - they 100% not changed by another application between test runs.

Why Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting.Conditions.ChecksumCondition always return different checksum in Assert method?

Comment: How are you getting your expected values? Are they perhaps order dependent? If so, you don't have an `ORDER BY` clause on your query so there's no guarantee on the order in which the rows come back.

Comment: @Ben Thul , from same query, inserted to ChecksumCondition configuration dialog box. Actual - from Assert error exception(Result Message: Checksum mismatch: Expected -1089799051 Actual -365205360). And it's not order dependency problem - with order by first(and only one) result column it's anyway returns different value in each test run.